# Is there a gRPC endpoint for Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-storage, grpc

I am trying to access Google Cloud Storage using the Swift programming language. Unfortunately, Google does not offer a client library for Swift. If Cloud Storage exposed a gRPC endpoint, I could simply "generate my own" using [SwiftGRPC](http://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift).

Therefore, does Google Cloud Storage offer a gRPC endpoint, and if so, where could I find the service's definition file in `protobuf` format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage does not have a gRPC endpoint at this time.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any plans to add one, or is there a Buganizer issue I could track/upvote?